# State-space filters in fixed-point?

Tags: matlab, filters, audio, state-space, fixed-point

I am having difficulties implementing [state-space filters](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/%7Ejos/filters/State_Space_Filters.html) in (32-bit) fixed-point. This is because the coefficients have a huge dynamic range, for example (MATLAB code):

```
A = [0.989923894 -116924.375; 4.34027786e-10 1];
B = [1; 0];
C = [0.010076086 1];
D = 0;
```

When converted to biquad sections:

```
[sos, gain] = ss2sos(A,B,C,D);
```

the coeffs are pretty normal:

```
sos = 0    1.0000   -1.0000    1.0000   -1.9899    0.9900

b0 =  0.0000
b1 =  1.0000
b2 = -1.0000
a0 =  1.0000
a1 = -1.9899
a2 =  0.9900

gain = 0.0101
```

Is there anything I can do to make my life easier? Any advice most welcome.

Comment: Do you need to implement the filters in space-state form ? Or would an SOS form be ok?

Comment: Should be state-space because it's time-varying.

Comment: State space models are not a unique system representation due to using any nonsingular similarity transformation. So you could use such similarity transformation which balances this. Does the build in matlab function [balreal](https://se.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/balreal.html) yield desirable results?

Comment: is this written in C or C++?  do you have a `fixed` type?  or will you be implementing this using `int` or `long`?

Comment: and ***all*** of those forms, whether they be Direct Form I or Direct Form II or transposed Direct forms or the Chamberlin form or the Lattice form or the Gold-Rader form or something else, ***all*** of those forms can be expressed in state-space model.  the state-space model is a generalization of ***all*** of the other structures.  there are a zillion different ways of implementing the same filter (from an I/O perspective) with the state-space model.

Comment: I'm implementing this in C on Tensilica HiFi3 platform; no fp unit, just 32x32-bit multiplication (two multiplications per single cycle).

Comment: okay, so the 32-bit words are called "`int`"?  what are the 64-bit result of a 32$\times$32-bit called?  are they "`long`"?  `int` and `long` are ANSI.  is there a type called `fixed`?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson No, there isn't a `fixed` type.

Comment: okay, so this is unrelated to the state-space model, but do you know how to do fixed-point processing in C using `int` and `long`?  you will need to know some information from Cadence about it.  i only looked at the [quickie spec sheet](https://ip.cadence.com/uploads/928/TIP_PB_HiFi_DSP_FINAL-pdf).  it says that you can do 4 simultaneous MACs with 24×24, but 32×32 is only 2 MACs per instruction cycle.  you have to decide if you really need those extra 8 bits.  then you have to find out from the C compiler manual exactly what the syntax is for 32×32 $\to$ 64 bit is in C.  get that first.

Comment: actually, it looks like [here](https://ip.cadence.com/uploads/103/SWdev-pdf) that they may have a variety of fixed-point types.  like `xd_q8_31d` .  you wanna really check this out.  there might be an easy way to do fixed-point processing in C, but you have to look at what the compiler does for you.

Answer (score 2):

Do a similarity transform on the state-space equation*.

I'm assuming your original system is
$$\begin{matrix}
x_n = A x_{n-1} +  B u_n \\
y_n = C x_n
\end{matrix}$$

Let
$T = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 5 \cdot 10^{-8}\end{bmatrix}$ (Note that I arbitrarily chose this by educated eyeball and some messing around -- *any* $T$ that is invertible will work in theory, so you're free to chose one that makes your problem pretty.)

Then define $\chi_n = T x_n$. The system
$$\begin{matrix}
\chi_n = T^{-1} A T \chi_{n-1} + T^{-1} B u_n \\
y_n = C\,T\,\chi_n
\end{matrix}$$

has exactly the same input-output dynamics as your original system.  The difference is that $T^{-1} A T \simeq \begin{bmatrix}0.98992389 & -0.00584622 \\0.00868056 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ is much better conditioned numerically.  You'll still have the issue that your C matrix is "poorly conditioned", but that pretty much means that the second element of $\chi$ doesn't have much effect on your final answer.

* "Linear Systems" by Thomas Kailath, pp 53-54, Prentice-Hall, 1980

Comment: And if all you're interested in doing is to implement a SISO filter, then just use a biquad.

Comment: and, if it's fixed-point, OP should use Direct Form 1 (with a double-wide accumulator) or, perhaps, a Lattice form.